# pm2 not starting services automatically on reboot

Tags: node.js, pm2

`pm2` is not resurrecting the services on reboot. I am using an EC2 instance with RHEL8.
This is how I have setup pm2:

```
 1. pm2 start service1
 2. pm2 startup
 3. run the cmd returned by this
 4. pm2 save
 5. sudo reboot
```

Following are the logs on running this command `systemctl -l status pm2-ec2-user`:

```
● pm2-ec2-user.service - PM2 process manager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pm2-ec2-user.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-06-15 21:24:35 UTC; 662ms ago
     Docs: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
  Process: 1528 ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jun 15 21:24:35 ip-172-31-0-225.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: pm2-ec2-user.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jun 15 21:24:35 ip-172-31-0-225.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: pm2-ec2-user.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 15 21:24:35 ip-172-31-0-225.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start PM2 process manager.
```

When I run the same command (`/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect`) manually after reboot, it works. But somehow this is not working  automatically.

Comment: Can this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490707

Comment: Thanks @AndreyPopov. Checking the above link, I was able to look into the audit log and I see there are some errors. `type=AVC msg=audit(1623788791.829:21): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=760 comm="(pm2)"`. But I am still not able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: It's pretty important how you installed pm2 on your system and if it has all the permissions to execute things around. But surely you should dig around permissions...

Comment: Try `systemctl enable pm2-root`